# Set autofocus => true in custom_fields added on devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've added 2 new fields on my devise users: `:first_name` and `:last_name`

So in the registration page I've added these new fields to be filled by user.

```
  <div>
    <%= f.label :first_name %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus => true %>
  </div>

  <div>
    <%= f.label :last_name %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>
```

Initially the autofocus was set on `:email` field, but now I changed to `:first_name` field.

The problem is when I access this page i get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `autofocus' for #<#<Class:0x361ef18>:0x449d630>
```

What forgot I to do in my rails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `:` before the `autofocus` symbol, change it to:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true %>
```

Comment: Oh well, my fault! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

it should be `:autofocus` and not `autofocus`

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, :autofocus => true %>
```

The colon `:` is missing at the start, should be a symbol, else its treated as if local variable/assign.